# Cartesian product of two balls

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, cross-product

Consider the following exercise:
Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$ be an arbitrary point and let $\varepsilon>0$. Show that there are positive real numbers $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ such that $$B^n(a,\varepsilon_1)\times B^m(b,\varepsilon_2)\subset B^{n+m}((a,b),\varepsilon)$$

This seems as an intuitive result, however, my problem is that I do not know how I should start writing this particular proof. Any tips, hint or help in general is welcome.

Comment: Can you visualize the case $n=m=1$?

Comment: In that case, what I would do is: Let $t=(a,b), k=(a',b')$ be points in $mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $N(t,k)=\max(|a-a'|,|b-b'|).

Comment: Not sure what $a',b'$ are and what you do with $N(t,k)\,.$ Is it not enough to realize that the Cartesian product of any finite number of bounded sets is bounded ?